# Undo --install-types with mypy

Tags: mypy

I had a problem with mypy on my project raising an error `Library stubs not installed for "yaml"` so I ran it with the `--install-types` flag to test if it fixes the issue. It did. But now I would like to reproduce the issue because I want to be sure that it works with my lint pipeline (specifically I want to see the effect of adding or not adding the `--non-interactive` option for mypy when running `arc lint`).

So my question is:
Is there a way to unfix whatever issue `mypy --install-types` fixed?
Where are stubs installed on my machine?
How can I find and uninstall them?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
pip list | grep types
pip uninstall types-PyYAML
```